# Selenium Grid with Selenese html based test cases

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Can I any body help in following questions?

1. How to use Selenium Grid with Selenese html based test cases?
2. How to distribute load for Selenese test cases on different machines using Selenium Grid and Selenium RC?

Please reply. Thanks

Sajjad

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted, Selenium Grid only helps with the routing of Selenium RC requests to registered workers.  If you come up with some way to run your Selenese through Selenium RC, that would work.  Otherwise, there's no special handling of Selenese through Selenium Grid.